# Combining String in Yii Framework

Tags: php, html, yii, string-concatenation

I want to ask about the way to combine string in this code. Specifically, first_name and last_name. Thank you for your helping before.

```
<?php
/* @var $this AuthassignmentController */
/* @var $data Authassignment */
$datamodel = (Member::model()->findByPK($data->userid));
?>

<div class="view">

    <b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('userid')); ?>:</b>
    <?php echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->userid), array('view', 'id' => $data->userid)); ?>
    <br />
    <b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('username')); ?>:</b>
    <?php echo CHtml::encode(CHtml::encode($datamodel->first_name), array('view', 'id' => $data->userid)); ?>
    <br />
    <b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('itemname')); ?>:</b>
    <?php echo CHtml::encode($data->itemname); ?>
    <br />

</div>
```

Comment: Like `$datamodel->first_name . ' ' . $datamodel->last_name`? Or can you elaborate your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you nested two encode functions, the first with an invalid second parameter.

It should be:

```
<?php echo CHtml::encode($datamodel->first_name).' '.CHtml::encode($datamodel->last_name); ?>
```

Comment: Good catch:) It easy to miss something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

just like you are combining a normal php code without using framework. just use dot.

```
<?php echo CHtml::encode(CHtml::encode($datamodel->first_name.' '.CHtml::encode($datamodel->last_name), array('view', 'id' => $data->userid)); ?>
```